# Lightning Experience configuration converter doesnt show VF pages after Scanning org

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

Its shows this message after scan is complete instead of showing list of vf pages.

*Your org doesn’t have any Visualforce pages, or none of your Visualforce pages fit the criteria for this list view. Try a different list view. Or, if you ran your scan in a sandbox org, try running it again in your production org.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visualforce reports look for those visualforce pages which have been used by any user in your org in the last 90 days. If you have any visualforce page which has not been used in the last 90 days, the tool will not consider them.

To get the correct report, Run it for your production org. Also, you will get the report in CSV format to your mail.